# Drools - KIEBase Deserialization Exception while using Trait

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, drools

We are using **Drools 6.3 and JDK 1.8** version for implementing certain business rules in our program. We have written one of our business rule using the trait/don concept from drools as below:

```
declare Patient
@Traitable
end

declare trait PatientTrait end

declare EvalTime
@role( event)
@timestamp (evalTime)
evalTime: Date
end

declare Fired
  guid: String
end

declare trait eligible_adult_patient extends com.test.trait.PatientTrait end


rule "External Data eligible_adult_patient"
when
    EvalTime($evalTime: evalTime)
    $item: Patient(birthDate before [23741d] $evalTime)

then
    don($item, eligible_adult_patient.class, true);

end

rule "Rule logic for rule585bf9ed_a1ae_46de_8f5c_65ce605d48b9"
when
    not(Fired( guid == "585bf9ed-a1ae-46de-8f5c-65ce605d48b9" ))
    patient:Patient()
    (exists(eligible_adult_patient())))
then
    insert(new Fired("585bf9ed-a1ae-46de-8f5c-65ce605d48b9"));
end
```

We generate the KIEBase using the following code:

```
KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
```

Once the KIEBase is generated we try to Serialize the KIEBase and **store it into the DB as a Blob.** 
For the next request to the rule we try to **retrieve the KIEBase from DB and de-serialize** it. During which we get the **following exception**:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.drools.core.reteoo.TraitObjectTypeNode; no valid constructor
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:150)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:790)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.BetaNode.readExternal(BetaNode.java:219)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.NotNode.readExternal(NotNode.java:63)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1842)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.AbstractTerminalNode.readExternal(AbstractTerminalNode.java:62)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.RuleTerminalNode.readExternal(RuleTerminalNode.java:159)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1842)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1396)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.readExternal(ReteooBuilder.java:405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1842)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.readExternal(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:500)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1842)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.drools.core.util.DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn(DroolsStreamUtils.java:205)
    at org.drools.core.util.DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn(DroolsStreamUtils.java:161)
    at org.drools.core.util.DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn(DroolsStreamUtils.java:131)
    at org.drools.core.util.DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn(DroolsStreamUtils.java:116)
```

When we looked at the *org.drools.core.reteoo.TraitObjectTypeNode* class it doesn't have no-arg constructor which is causing the above issue while de-serializing.

**So my question is:**

1. Any recommended resolution for the above de-serialization issue
2. Is it a recommended approach of storing the KIEBase only in in-memory cache or is it also fine to store the KIEBase in a storage(like DB)/distributed cache (serializing & de-serializing)

Any help in this regard is appreciated

Punith

Comment: Jira Ticket has been created to fix this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1123